# Why do parentheses change the iterating type?

Tags: powershell

```
PS > Get-Item env: | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object GetType

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    True     ValueCollection                          System.Object

PS > (Get-Item env:) | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object GetType

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DictionaryEntry                          System.ValueType
```

Preamble:
I was wondering why I cannot use Where-Object to filter `Get-Item env:`

P.S. Just in case, the solution to filter env:

1. `(Get-Item env:) | Where-Object Name -eq 'PUBLIC'`
2. `Get-Item env:\* | Where-Object Name -eq 'PUBLIC'`
3. `Get-ChildItem env: | Where-Object Name -eq 'PUBLIC'`
4. `gi env: |% GetEnumerator |? Name -eq 'PUBLIC'` (added after [@santisq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66554034/1167345) answer, he deleted it)

However despite of the fact thar `Get-Item env:` list all the env variables (however the documentation said it should not while * is not set pointed), you cannot filter `Get-Item env: | Where-Object Name -eq 'PUBLIC` because `Get-Item env: | Measure-Object`  Count is 1

Environment:
PSVersion 5.1.19041.610

Comment: `Env` is a PsDrive just like `C`, but with a different provider (`Environment` provider). `Get-Item` returns just the item itself. Using `()` forces enumeration and runs the inner command to completion before sending anything through the pipeline. `Get-Item env:` returns a single collection, which is why the count is 1. `(Get-Item env:)` enumerates the inner collection, which is why the count is greater than 1. If you want the items contained in a PsDrive, you should just use `Get-ChildItem env:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Env` is a PsDrive just like `C`, but with a different provider (`Environment` provider).

[Get-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-7.1) returns just the item itself and not the item contents by default. It has the capability of returning the item contents. Using [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#grouping-operator--) `()` forces enumeration and runs the inner command to completion before sending anything through the pipeline.

`Get-Item env:` returns a single, unenumerated collection, which is why the count is 1. `(Get-Item env:)` enumerates the inner collection, which is why the count is greater than 1. If you want the items contained in a PsDrive, you should just use `Get-ChildItem env:`. Appending your path with `\*` instructs the command to return each single child item matched by `*`, which is the same as `Get-ChildItem` without the trailing `\*`. ***Only when the collection is enumerated can you apply filtering logic against the contained items.***

```
# No enumeration
Get-Item -Path env: | Measure | Select -Expand Count
1
Get-Item -Path env: | Where Name -eq 'PUBLIC' # returns nothing

# Forced enumeration
(Get-Item -Path env:) | Measure | Select -Expand Count
44
(Get-Item -Path env:) | Where Name -eq 'PUBLIC'
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PUBLIC                         C:\Users\Public

# Implied enumeration by returning targeting child items
Get-Item -Path env:\* | Measure | Select -Expand Count
44

# returns child items of target
Get-ChildItem -Path env: | Measure | Select -Expand Count
44
```

Comment: Nicely done; to add to that: _Non-hierarchical_ PowerShell providers unexpectedly output the collection of their items _as a single object_ when targeted _by drive name only_. While that could be construed as helpful fallback functionality for non-hierarchical providers  (hierarchical providers report their _root container_ in this case), the potential for confusion is greater than the potential benefit.